# Bounded Quadratic Congruence Problem Variant (for some specific Residue)

Tags: complexity-theory

**Given:** 3 positive integers $a,b,L$. **Problem:** Is there a positive integer $x<L$ such that $x^2≡ a(mod\ b)$?

The above problem is **NPComplete** (as mentioned in G&J) even if we have the factorization of $b$ given. My query is the following:

Is there some specific value of $a$ (say $a_0$) such that, if we limit the original problem (the residue) to only $a_0$, the problem ceases to be **NPComplete** (and much easily solvable than the generic case) ?

My guess is for any/each specific $a_0$ the problem still remains **NPComplete** but I am not certain. Anyone please ?

Comment: The problem becomes easy when $a=0$ or $a=1$, and (I believe) when $a$ is a square. So the real question is whether there exists a value of $a$ for which the problem remains NP-complete.

Comment: thanks a lot. Would it be possible for you to help with a link/info for (a=1) case  (and also $a$ = square) ?

Comment: Take it as an exercise.

Comment: I will try. "So the real question is whether there exists a value of a for which the problem remains NP-complete". I was going to follow up with the exact same question :), but I am guessing this is still unknown ?

Comment: This is unknown to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If $a=1$, the problem is no longer NP-complete; the answer to the problem is always "yes, there is such a positive integer".